# Cassandra: low cardinality partition

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, denormalization

Let's say I have a table, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
  user UUID,
  seq INT,
  group TEXT,
  time BIGINT,
  PRIMARY KEY ((user), seq)
);
```

This follows the desired pattern of Cassandra, with good distribution across partitions (assuming the default Murmur3 hash partitioner).

However, I also need to (rarely) perform range queries on and in time order. This doesn't seem possible in Cassandra. In reality I do need to access the data by group, so `(group, time)` is acceptable. Since there doesn't seem a way to have secondary index have multiple columns, I guess the right thing is to denormalize, into something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE UsersByGroupTime (
  user UUID,
  seq INT,
  group TEXT,
  time BIGINT,
  PRIMARY KEY ((group), time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time ASC);
```

This works entirely as it should, except that `group` is really low cardinality, let's say `('A','B','C')`, and uneven distribution across users. Since queries on that table is rare, I'm not worried about hot nodes, but I am worried about uneven distribution, perhaps even a single node getting all.

Is this a common scenario and is there any way to mitigate this or are there alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

One technique to help avoid hot-spots in Cassandra time series models, is in making use of a "time bucket."  Essentially what you would do is determine the "happy medium" level of time precision that provides adequate data distribution, while also being known and semi-convenient to query by.

For the purposes of this example, I'll choose year and month ("yyyyMM").  *Note:  I have no idea if year and month will work for you...it's just an example.*  Once you determine your time bucket, you would add it as an additional partition key, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE UsersByGroupTime (
  user UUID,
  seq INT,
  group TEXT,
  time TIMEUUID,
  yearmonth BIGINT,
  PRIMARY KEY ((group, yearmonth), time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

After inserting some rows, queries like this will work:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT group, yearmonth, dateof(time), time, seq, user 
FROM usersbygrouptime WHERE group='B' AND yearmonth=201505;

 group | yearmonth | dateof(time)             | time                                 | seq | user
-------+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------------
     B |    201505 | 2015-05-16 10:04:10-0500 | ceda56f0-fbdc-11e4-bd43-21b264d4c94d |   1 | d57ba8a4-db24-440c-a983-b1dd6b0d2e27
     B |    201505 | 2015-05-16 10:04:09-0500 | ce1cac40-fbdc-11e4-bd43-21b264d4c94d |   1 | 66d07cbb-a2ff-4d56-8fa1-14dfaf684474
     B |    201505 | 2015-05-16 10:04:08-0500 | cd525760-fbdc-11e4-bd43-21b264d4c94d |   1 | 07b589ac-4d5f-401e-a34f-e3479e269e01
     B |    201505 | 2015-05-16 10:04:06-0500 | cc76c470-fbdc-11e4-bd43-21b264d4c94d |   1 | 984f85b5-ea58-4cf8-b512-43abacb227c9

(4 rows)
```

Now that may or may not help you query-wise, so you will need to spend some time ensuring that you pick an appropriate time bucket.  But, this does help in terms of data distribution in the ring, which you can see with the `token` function:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT group, yearmonth, token(group,yearmonth)
FROM usersbygrouptime ;

 group | yearmonth | token(group, yearmonth)
-------+-----------+-------------------------
     A |    201503 |    -3784784210711042553
     A |    201504 |     -610775546464185720
     B |    201505 |     6232834565276653514
     B |    201505 |     6232834565276653514
     B |    201505 |     6232834565276653514
     B |    201505 |     6232834565276653514
     A |    201505 |     8281745497436252453
     A |    201505 |     8281745497436252453
     A |    201505 |     8281745497436252453
     A |    201505 |     8281745497436252453
     A |    201505 |     8281745497436252453
     A |    201505 |     8281745497436252453

(12 rows)
```

Notice how different tokens are generated for each group/yearmonth pair, even though some of them have the same group ("A").